# DocuSign "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR" Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a new envelope using the DocuSign REST API version 2. This is the response I'm getting:

```
{
    "errorCode" : "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
    "message" : "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
}
```

Here's the (sanitized and word wrapped) data that's being sent. Note that we're using OAuth2.

```
POST https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes
Content-Length: 72523
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: bearer{oauth2_token}

{"status": "created",
 "documents": [
   {"documentBase64": "<DELETED_BASE64_DATA>", "name": "Sample Document",
    "documentId": "1"}
 ],
 "emailSubject": "Documents to Sign",
 "recipients": {
   "signers": [
     {"recipientId": "1", "email": "user@example.com",
      "routingOrder": "1", "name": "Example User"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Any thoughts as to which index is out of bounds?

Thanks

Comment: You need to make a multipart/form-data request to create a DocuSign envelope from a local document (as opposed to from a Template).  You also have the document bytes in the wrong location, they are only part of the `document` object when using `compositeTemplates`.  What language are you using?  I can probably whip something up for you...

Comment: @Ergin I tried using multipart/form-data as well, but got the same result. Using base64 data in the document object (but without OAuth2) worked on the DocuSign test server. We finally got in touch with DocuSign tech support and they're looking into the issue. They seem to think it might be a problem with their parsing of the PDF file on the production servers.

Comment: Yes but as mentioned you have the document bytes in the wrong location. They don't go on the document JSON object, they go in the second part of the `multipart/form-data` request.  I'll post a C# sample for you...

Answer (score 0):

You have the document bytes in the wrong location, and you need to make a proper `multipart/form-data` request to create a new DocuSign envelope.  Here is a full code sample in C#, copy a document to the same directory and fill in the variables at the top and it should work for you.

Note that this was copied from the [DocuSign API Walkthroughs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/api-explorer):

```
// DocuSign API Walkthrough 04 in C# - Request Signature on a Document
//
// To run this sample: 
//  1) Create a new .NET project.
//  2) Add 4 assembly references to the project:  System, System.Net, System.XML, and System.XML.Linq
//  3) Update the email, password, integrator key, recipient name, and document name in the code
//  4) Copy a sample PDF file into project directory with same name as the document name you set in the code
//  5) Compile and Run
//
// NOTE 1: The DocuSign REST API accepts both JSON and XML formatted http requests.  These C# API walkthroughs
//     demonstrate the use of XML format, whereas the other walkthroughs show examples in JSON format.
using System; 
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace DocuSignAPIWalkthrough04 
{
    public class RequestSignatureOnDocument
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // ENTER VALUES FOR THE FOLLOWING 6 VARIABLES:
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string username = "***";            // your account email
            string password = "***";            // your account password
            string integratorKey = "***";           // your account Integrator Key (found on Preferences -> API page)
            string recipientName = "***";           // recipient (signer) name
            string recipientEmail = "***";          // recipient (signer) email
            string documentName = "***";            // copy document with same name and extension into project directory (i.e. "test.pdf")
            string contentType = "application/pdf";     // default content type is PDF
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // additional variable declarations
            string baseURL = "";            // - we will retrieve this through the Login API call

            try {
                //============================================================================
                //  STEP 1 - Login API Call (used to retrieve your baseUrl)
                //============================================================================

                // Endpoint for Login api call (in demo environment):
                string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";

                // set request url, method, and headers.  No body needed for login api call
                HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest( url, "GET", null, username, password, integratorKey);

                // read the http response
                string response = getResponseBody(request);

                // parse baseUrl from response body
                baseURL = parseDataFromResponse(response, "baseUrl");

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));

                //============================================================================
                //  STEP 2 - Send Signature Request from Template
                //============================================================================

                /*
                    This is the only DocuSign API call that requires a "multipart/form-data" content type.  We will be 
                    constructing a request body in the following format (each newline is a CRLF):

                    --AAA
                    Content-Type: application/xml
                    Content-Disposition: form-data

                    <XML BODY GOES HERE>
                    --AAA
                    Content-Type:application/pdf
                    Content-Disposition: file; filename="document.pdf"; documentid=1 

                    <DOCUMENT BYTES GO HERE>
                    --AAA--
                 */

                // append "/envelopes" to baseURL and use for signature request api call
                url = baseURL + "/envelopes";

                // construct an outgoing XML formatted request body (JSON also accepted)
                // .. following body adds one signer and places a signature tab 100 pixels to the right
                // and 100 pixels down from the top left corner of the document you supply
                string xmlBody = 
                    "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" + 
                    "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>" + 
                    "<status>sent</status>" +   // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft in your account
                        // add document(s)
                    "<documents>" +
                    "<document>" + 
                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" + 
                    "<name>" + documentName + "</name>" + 
                    "</document>" + 
                    "</documents>" +
                        // add recipient(s)
                    "<recipients>" + 
                    "<signers>" + 
                    "<signer>" + 
                    "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" + 
                    "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +   
                    "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +      
                    "<tabs>" + 
                    "<signHereTabs>" + 
                    "<signHere>" + 
                    "<xPosition>100</xPosition>" + // default unit is pixels
                    "<yPosition>100</yPosition>" + // default unit is pixels
                    "<documentId>1</documentId>" + 
                    "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" + 
                    "</signHere>" +
                    "</signHereTabs>" + 
                    "</tabs>" + 
                    "</signer>" + 
                    "</signers>" + 
                    "</recipients>" +  
                    "</envelopeDefinition>";

                // set request url, method, headers.  Don't set the body yet, we'll set that separelty after
                // we read the document bytes and configure the rest of the multipart/form-data request
                request = initializeRequest( url, "POST", null, username, password, integratorKey);

                // some extra config for this api call
                configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(request, xmlBody, documentName, contentType);

                // read the http response
                response = getResponseBody(request);

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Call Result: \n\n" + prettyPrintXml(response));
            }
            catch (WebException e) {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response) {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(prettyPrintXml(text));
                    }
                }
            }
        } // end main()

        //***********************************************************************************************
        // --- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---
        //***********************************************************************************************
        public static HttpWebRequest initializeRequest(string url, string method, string body, string email, string password, string intKey)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
            request.Method = method;
            addRequestHeaders( request, email, password, intKey );
            if( body != null )
                addRequestBody(request, body);
            return request;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestHeaders(HttpWebRequest request, string email, string password, string intKey)
        {
            // authentication header can be in JSON or XML format.  XML used for this walkthrough:
            string authenticateStr = 
                "<DocuSignCredentials>" + 
                    "<Username>" + email + "</Username>" +
                    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" + 
                    "<IntegratorKey>" + intKey + "</IntegratorKey>" + 
                    "</DocuSignCredentials>";
            request.Headers.Add ("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void addRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request, string requestBody)
        {
            // create byte array out of request body and add to the request object
            byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (requestBody);
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            dataStream.Write (body, 0, requestBody.Length);
            dataStream.Close ();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static void configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(HttpWebRequest request, string xmlBody, string docName, string contentType)
        {
            // overwrite the default content-type header and set a boundary marker
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY";

            // start building the multipart request body
            string requestBodyStart = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" +
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n" +
                    "\r\n" +
                    xmlBody + "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +    // our xml formatted envelopeDefinition
                    "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n" +
                    "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"" + docName + "\"; documentId=1\r\n" +
                    "\r\n";
            string requestBodyEnd = "\r\n--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n";

            // read contents of provided document into the request stream
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(docName);

            // write the body of the request
            byte[] bodyStart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyStart.ToString());
            byte[] bodyEnd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyEnd.ToString());
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, requestBodyStart.ToString().Length);

            // Read the file contents and write them to the request stream.  We read in blocks of 4096 bytes
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = fileStream.Read(buf, 0, 4096) ) > 0) {
                dataStream.Write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            dataStream.Write(bodyEnd, 0, requestBodyEnd.ToString().Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string getResponseBody(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            // read the response stream into a local string
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string parseDataFromResponse(string response, string searchToken)
        {
            // look for "searchToken" in the response body and parse its value
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response))) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == searchToken))
                        return reader.ReadString();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string prettyPrintXml(string xml)
        {
            // print nicely formatted xml
            try {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                return doc.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                return xml;
            }
        }
    } // end class
} // end namespace
```